# How to use retrofit to parse json data from a weblink into a map activity in android

Tags: android, google-maps, retrofit, retrofit2, mapactivity

I have been reading about retrofit and how it is a better alternative then the traditional way of parsing JSON data. I wanted to know if someone could give me an example on how to parse JSON data from a url or website and add markers to a map activity using retrofit?